# Using different tenses in single sentence!

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

here is a sentence from this animation Incredibles 2 :

> Any thought we had about being Supers again is fantasy.

I can't understand the logic behind tenses here... we have **thought** and **had** which are past tense and then in the same sentence **is** which is simple present!

I'm confused may you please help...

And here is the full context:

> What are we gonna do?
>
> I don't know.
>
> Maybe Dicker will find something?
>
> Dicker is done, Bob.
>
> **> Any thought we had about being Supers again is fantasy.**
>
> One of us has gotta get a job.
>
> One of us?
>
> ...

Comment: The "logic" is simply that if indeed there ***were*** any such thoughts, and regardless of whether they were recognised as such at the original time of thinking them, it ***is*** now apparent that they ***are*** fantasy / unrealistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right in saying that the past and present tense have been used.

**Thought** and **had** are past tense and here it means they used to have thoughts about being supers (super heroes)

But know it **is** (present tense) fantasy (impossible/imaginary)

Comment: So this is a correct sentence: Any think we have about being Supers is fantasy.

Comment: @SaraRee Thought would be correct as thought is a noun, rather than think which is a verb and incorrect

Comment: @SaraRee More the point, the mix of the tenses is fine because the thought *remains* a fantasy. Backshifting is optional. *I **told** her that the Earth **is** round.* This is acceptable because it's a general truth that continues to be true, regardless of time. If you were to say ***was*** *fantasy* or ***was*** *round*, it would be possible to interpret it as meaning that it no longer *is* fantasy or round. (But that doesn't mean that the past tense would be wrong—just that either can be used, depending on your preference.)